# Retrieving Column Names and Data types in PLSQL

Tags: sql, plsql

I am writing a PL SQL block that retrieves all the columns and the data types of the tables in the database. I am able to get the columns , but not the datatypes. Looking for suggestions for a good approach. Any help would be appreciated. My code is as follows

```
ACCEPT p_1 PROMPT 'Please enter the Table Name'

DECLARE
    v_table_name    VARCHAR2(40) :='&p_1';
    -- First cursor 
    CURSOR get_tables IS    
        SELECT DISTINCT table_name 
        FROM user_tables 
        WHERE UPPER(table_name) = UPPER(v_table_name);
    --Second cursor 
    CURSOR get_columns IS
        SELECT DISTINCT column_name
        FROM user_tab_columns
        WHERE table_name = v_table_name;
    v_column_name   VARCHAR2(100);
    -- Third Cursor
    CURSOR get_types IS
        SELECT data_type 
        FROM user_tab_columns
        WHERE table_name = v_table_name;

    v_data_type user_tab_columns.data_type%type;
BEGIN
    -- Open first cursor
    OPEN get_tables;
    FETCH get_tables INTO v_table_name;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' ');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Table = ' || v_table_name );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('=========================');
    CLOSE get_tables;
    -- Open second cursor
    OPEN get_columns;
    FETCH get_columns INTO v_column_name;
    WHILE get_columns%FOUND LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  ' || v_column_name);
        FETCH get_columns INTO v_column_name;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE get_columns;
    --Open Third Cursor
    OPEN get_types;
    FETCH get_types into v_data_type;
    WHILE get_types%FOUND LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' ' || v_data_type );
        FETCH get_types into v_data_type;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE get_types;     
END;
```

My error states PLS-00371: at most one declaration for 'V_DATA_TYPE' is permitted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a PLSQL guru but here's my grain.

```
Select data_type from user_tab_columns where TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName'
```

Props to Eric, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6738753/1326923) thread and his answer.

Remember you can use `DESC` command to describe an Oracle Table, View, Synonym, package or Function. It will give you name, data_type and lengh.
And if this actually works for you, you should be able to get the data for all of your tables, although I'm not a huge fan of cursors, you should do fine.

Try this:

```
-- Open second cursor
            OPEN get_columns;
            LOOP
            FETCH get_columns INTO v_column_name, v_data_type;
            EXIT WHEN get_columns%NOTFOUND;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  ' || v_column_name);
            END LOOP;
            CLOSE get_columns;
    END LOOP;
```

But be careful on the datatype you've chosen for `v_data_type` variable.

Comment: my major concern is how do I declare a variable that would accept values from your select statement , considering the fact that the data types could be date , Number  , char varchar etc

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with that variable. But I'd place the result of the data_type query in a plain simple string (convert or do what you have to) and the move forward from there.

Comment: Well  , my current query returns all the tables with columns , I wish to return the data types as well. I am confused as to how to use the select statement given by you. Can you give a coding example??

Comment: When you Open cursor number 2, you     FETCH get_columns     into the column_name variable, you should add the other one too (data_type). Your cursor 2 definition selects 2 things, and you want to place those two things into one variable.

Comment: exactly my question , what should be the datatype for v_data_type? I apologize if this is being stretched but its this small thing that I cant get hold of

Comment: if you want a single variable to hold all the data types inside, then you should declare it as string (varchar) and CAST every FETCH result to varchar. Then you move on.

Comment: I think I figured it out  , Thanks Daniel!!

Comment: In sqlDeveloper, it only lists a subset of the tables I have access to. does anyone know a work around? ty

Answer (score 3):

Good effort, but too much code. you need a short vacation :)

```
SELECT table_name,
       column_name,
       data_type,
       data_length,
       nullable
FROM cols
WHERE table_name='&YOUR_TABLE'
ORDER BY column_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your block has way too much code.  This is all you need:

```
begin
    for r in ( select column_name, data_type
               from    user_tab_columns 
               where table_name = upper('&&p_1')
               order by column_id )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(r.column_name ||' is '|| r.data_type );
    end loop;
```

end;

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem. It can be viewed here: [Retrieving Table Structure with Dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022808/retrieving-table-structure-with-dynamic-sql/39024607#39024607).

Of things to note, I made sure that if data_scale = 0 I indicated it was to be a Integer, and if it was >0, it was a Double.