# View/edit table structure with SQL in Base

Tags: sql, database-design, hsqldb

I'm JPablos and I trying to view the structure of "orders" table.

I'm using Base

`LibreOffice Versión: 5.2.0.4 Id. de compilación: 1:5.2.0~rc4-0ubuntu1~xenial2 Subprocesos de CPU: 1; Versión de SO: Linux 4.4`

SQL statement

```
select listagg(column_name ||','|| data_type ||','||   case
 when data_type in ('VARCHAR2', 'NVARCHAR2', 'CHAR', 'RAW')
   then to_char(data_length)
 when data_type = 'NUMBER' and (data_precision is not null or data_scale is not null)
   then data_precision || case
 when data_scale > 0 then '.' || data_scale
 end
end, ',') within group (order by column_id) 
from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'orders';
```

Then SQL informs me

> 1: Access is denied: LISTAGG in statement [select listagg(]

Note: obviously... the easy way in Base UI: select "orders" / right click / Edit, and yes it opens the structure of table "orders". But, I want to use SQL to do it.

Thanks in advance

JPablos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after all it is a SQL statement to do the query object of my question above, and is:

```
SELECT * FROM "INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."SYSTEM_COLUMNS" WHERE "TABLE_NAME" = 'Students'
```

Where "Students" is the name of a table used for this answer.

The SQL statement reports:

[Result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeHG7.png)

Best regards

JPablos

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement is written for the Oracle database. The `LISTAGG` function is not supported by HSQLDB.

If you use LibreOffice base together with the latest HSQLDB 2.3.4 (instead of the bundled version 1.8.0) then you can use the HSQLDB function `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: Thanks @fredt. I am learning to use SQL. The SQL statement used was a copy of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022808/retrieving-table-structure-with-dynamic-sql).

Now how can I use codeGROUP_CONCAT/code ?

Comment: You need to set up the HSQLDB 2.3.4 jar and learn how to use different functions from the HSQLDB docs. http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/index.html