# How to get the column name from the table using where condition too

Tags: php, sql

currently I have a cop_config table. What I want is to fetch some (not all) column names using where condition too. Right now, I am only able to  get all column name using the following code..

```
 $cop_value = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'cop_config' and is_nullable = 'NO'";
      $cop_result = $conn->query($cop_value);
      while($cop_row = $cop_result->fetch_assoc()){
      $cop_row = implode(',', $cop_row);
      echo $cop_row;
    }
```

currenlty my output is :

```
iddevice_keyfirst_pulse1first_pulse2first_pulse3first_pulse4first_pulse5first_pulse6first_pulse7first_pulse8second_pulse1second_pulse2second_pulse3second_pulse4second_pulse5second_pulse6second_pulse7second_pulse8
```

here is the table :
[image]

from the table what I want is to get only those column name according to device_key(in cop_config table) which has 1 in value. I am know my problem explanation is not so good please look at the table picture for better understanding tnx alot for your concern.

like in device_key YMR200, I just want to get the column name -- first_pulse1 & second_pulse2

similary for device_key VTA600 I want get the column name -- first_pulse3 & second_pulse4.

------------------------------☺☻♀♥♣♦♣WÇ--------------------------------
after a long search and google currently I am using

```
      $cop_value = "SELECT 'first_pulse1' from cop_config where first_pulse1 = 1 and device_key = 'VTA600' union 
select 'first_pulse2' from cop_config where first_pulse2 = 1 and device_key = 'VTA600' union 
select 'second_pulse1' from cop_config where second_pulse1 = 1 and device_key = 'VTA600' union 
select 'second_pulse2' from cop_config where second_pulse2 = 1 and device_key = 'VTA600'";


     $cop_result = $conn->query($cop_value);
      while($cop_row = $cop_result->fetch_assoc()){

      echo $cop_row;
    }
```

I knwo I have made blunder mistake here while fetching the value ... but I am dont know how to fetch the value from the query . Plz help
thanks ..

Comment: Did you search for PL/SQL based solutions ? What I could think of is using a cursor to iterate over the rows and get status of each device_key in other columns. It should work if you have a fixed number of columns.

Comment: tnx for your response. I will google PL/SQL and let you know if this work

Answer (score 3):

try
for sql server:

```
 SELECT
  sys.columns.name AS ColumnName
FROM
  sys.columns
WHERE
  sys.columns.name = 'first_pulse1'
  and
  exists(select top 1 * from cop_config where device_key = 'YMR200')
```

for Oracle:
[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452476/4993989)

PLSQL:
[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11838306/4993989)

for mySQL:
[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/193860/4993989)

Comment: tncx for your response. But still I am getting unexpected 'top' identifier

Comment: See other links i've posted after their tags?

Comment: I have gone through all of them but none of them seem very promising so I have moved on to union method..SELECT 'first_pulse1' from cop_config where first_pulse1 = 1 and device_key = 'VTA600' union 
select 'first_pulse2' from cop_config where first_pulse2 = 1 and device_key = 'VTA600' union 
select 'second_pulse1' from cop_config where second_pulse1 = 1 and device_key = 'VTA600' union 
select 'second_pulse2' from cop_config where second_pulse2 = 1 and device_key = 'VTA600'

Comment: In mysql workbench its is working as it should be in my real time php file its not running. I am lacking on how to fetch the value from the query. If you got any idea please help

Comment: I have updated my question plz go through it once if you solution help...

Comment: first try the query again removing 'top'. If still not works. Well, you keep searching and as soon as i will come up with something working i'll share it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally after long googling, I found this solution and its working. But I am not sure is it the right way of doing is it. Currently I am using union to get the data as required. here is the code

```
 $cop_value = "SELECT 'first_pulse1' from cop_config t where first_pulse1 = 1 and device_key = 'YMR200' union 
select 'first_pulse2' from cop_config t where first_pulse2 = 1 and device_key = 'YMR200' union
select 'first_pulse3' from cop_config t where first_pulse3 = 1 and device_key = 'YMR200' union
select 'first_pulse4' from cop_config t where first_pulse4 = 1 and device_key = 'YMR200' union
select 'first_pulse5' from cop_config t where first_pulse5 = 1 and device_key = 'YMR200' union
select 'first_pulse6' from cop_config t where first_pulse6 = 1 and device_key = 'YMR200' union 
select 'first_pulse7' from cop_config t where first_pulse7 = 1 and device_key = 'YMR200' union
select 'first_pulse8' from cop_config t where first_pulse8 = 1 and device_key = 'YMR200' union
select 'second_pulse1' from cop_config t where second_pulse1 = 1 and device_key = 'YMR200' union 
select 'second_pulse2' from cop_config t where second_pulse2 = 1 and device_key = 'YMR200' union
select 'second_pulse3' from cop_config t where second_pulse3 = 1 and device_key = 'YMR200' union
select 'second_pulse4' from cop_config t where second_pulse4 = 1 and device_key = 'YMR200' union
select 'second_pulse5' from cop_config t where second_pulse5 = 1 and device_key = 'YMR200' union
select 'second_pulse6' from cop_config t where second_pulse6 = 1 and device_key = 'YMR200' union
select 'second_pulse7' from cop_config t where second_pulse7 = 1 and device_key = 'YMR200' union
select 'second_pulse8' from cop_config t where second_pulse8 = 1 and device_key = 'YMR200'";


      $cop_result = $conn->query($cop_value);
      while($cop_row = $cop_result->fetch_assoc()){
      $cop_row = implode(',', $cop_row);
      echo $cop_row;
    }
```

and this is the output for device_key YMR200

```
first_pulse1second_pulse2
```